# How to pause / debug at the next possible breakpoint

Tags: python, pycharm

When running in debug mode in PyCharm, how can I get the code to put a breakpoint at the next immediate possible point (including client libraries).

What do I mean?

- Let's say I have a 10,000 line script that's running in debug mode.
- I'm not sure which library the code is currently in.
- If I put the breakpoint, the code will stop when it reaches there.
- But I don't know where it's stuck at right now.
- **Here is exactly where I want it to drop a breakpoint.**

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug toolbar has a [pause program](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debug-tool-window.html#debugtoolbar) button, which stops the execution at any point

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use "stepping" to get to the "next possible breakpoint". What I mean by that is, IDEs with debug usually let you "step" through code. See PyCharms documentation on debugging.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/stepping-through-the-program.html

Comment: yes I am aware, however, I want to see if the functionality I asked for exists. Because it is clear there is a listener that checks if the breakpoint is reached. I want to know if there is a way to force trigger this listener to break.